# Where are Transport Message Headers actually stored?

Tags: nservicebus

In NServiceBus 2.x, where are the Transport Message Headers actually stored?

I need to see the headers for debugging using either the built-in Queue Management GUI or QueueExplorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.x the headers go into the [Extension property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.extension.aspx) for MSMQ.